# Filter/ remove all null values of all elements using java8

Tags: java, java-8

I am trying to understand Java 8 features and use:
Below I want to filter null values from list
I know that using `.filter(n->n != null)` we can filter the `null` from list.
But I want to know that what to do if any element is `null`.
I also know that we can simply do like `.filter(n-> n.empName != null)` but what if I have many fields where types are not known while filtering.

Can we loop list inside filter and check for *n* elements each is `null` or not? Or please guide me an approach. Also when we convert list to map of `null` values are found it will throw error.
How do we do this using java8?

```
Employee[] arrayOfEmps = {
                new Employee(1, "Jeff Bezos", 100000.0), 
                new Employee(5, "Vijay", 700000.0),
                new Employee(2, "Bill Gates", 200000.0), 
                new Employee(4, "Shweta Oza", 500000.0),
                new Employee(0, null, 400000.0),
                null,
                new Employee(3, "Mark Zuckerberg", 300000.0)
            };

//Array -> Stream
        Stream<Employee> streamEmp = Stream.of(arrayOfEmps);

streamEmp.forEach(s->System.out.println(s.empID+" "+s.empName+" "+s.salary));

//Array -> List
        List<Employee> empList = Arrays.asList(arrayOfEmps);
        empList.forEach(System.out::println);
        
        //List -> Stream
        empList.stream();
        
        Map<Integer, String> map = new HashMap<Integer, String>();
        for(Employee e : empList) {
            map.put(e.empID, e.empName);
        }
        System.out.println(map);
        
        Map<Integer, String> map8 = new HashMap<Integer, String>();
        map8 = empList.stream().filter(n->n!=null).collect(Collectors.toMap(Employee::getEmpID, Employee::getEmpName));
        System.out.println(map8); //error
```

> I did it as follows just to get rid of null

```
List<Employee> dd = empList.stream().filter(currentEmp -> 
        {
            if (currentEmp == null)
            {
                return false;
            }
            if (currentEmp.getEmpName() == null)
            {
                return false;
            }
            if(currentEmp.getEmpID()==0) {
                return false;
            }
            if(currentEmp.getSalary()==0) {
                return false;
            }
            return true;
            
            // .. etc.
        }).collect(Collectors.toList());
        
        for(int i=0;i<dd.size();i++) {   
             System.out.println(dd.get(i).empName.toString());
             }
        map8 = dd.stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(Employee::getEmpID, Employee::getEmpName));
        System.out.println(map8);
```

Comment: why not check for each field in `filter` ?

Comment: You dont need to know types to use null checks. If you mean you have unknown fields, that's not really possible since you have access to the class you're checking

Comment: @Deadpool checking each field in filter we can do but just wandering what if we have 20 fields or so? .filter(n->n.empName!=null).filter(n->n.empId!=0).filter(n->n.empSalary!=0) this way. (can we loop in filter?)

Comment: Yes, you can have a loop in the lambda expression passed to `filter`. But you can’t express a “loop over fields”, unless using Reflection. Before you go that route, you should rethink your problem? Why are fields `null`, why is it a problem. If `null` values are a problem, you should not allow the fields to become `null` in the first place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you said, null Objects can be filtered. So the problem is objects of unknown class with null fields, like Employee, Manager, External. One could do it with *reflection* but that is ugly and slow. Better ensure in all those classes that they cannot have those null fields: [Objects.requireNonNull](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Objects.html#requireNonNull-T-). This ensures a fail-fast, so actually programmer testing will ensure correct code

```
class Employee {

    public Employee(String name) {
        Objects.requireNonNull(name);
```

When using some frameworks, one can use an annotation, like `@NonNull` for compile time code analysis.

```
    public Employee(@NonNull String name) {
```

And then one may guard to have the classes fields unassigned - when they are immutable - by `final` (constant fields):

```
    private final String name;

    public Employee(String name) {
        this.name = name; // Still name might be null, so:
        Objects.requireNonNull(name);
```

Not a perfect solution.

Comment: This should be a type annotation, `public Employee(@NonNull String name) {`. Or add `@NonNullByDefault` to the class declaration, to denote that all values should be non-null.

Comment: @Holger of course, and **`@NonNullByDefault`** should have been mentioned in this case.

Comment: You can write the assignment as `this.name = Objects.requireNonNull(name);`

Answer (score 1):

`filter()` takes as an argument a lambda expression, you could do whatever you want in it, as long as you return a `boolean`.

Example:

```java
       empList.stream().filter(currentEmp -> 
            {
                if (currentEmp == null)
                {
                    return false;
                }
                if (currentEmp.getName().trim().equals(""))
                {
                    return false;
                }
                
                // .. etc.
            }).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Regarding the second question, can you provide the error?

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
Map<Integer, String> map8 = new HashMap<Integer, String>();
  map8 = result.stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(Employee::getEmpID, Employee::getEmpName));
  System.out.println(map8);

Comment: This is thrown because you have null elements in your list, this should take care of that: 
`Arrays.asList(arrayOfEmps).stream().filter(Objects::nonNull).collect(Collectors.toMap(Employee::getEmpID, Employee::getEmpName));`

Comment: Is there any other way rather than checking for all fields
I got my solution but I am trying to understand that can i iterate to all elements at a time like empId, empName, empsalary and check at once? for example if i have 20-40 fields then won’t it get repetative same kind of checks for every field?

Comment: @oza I don't think there is another way, you have to check whether the field is null either in the beginning when you give it a value via a `setter` or after using `.filter()`

Answer (score 1):

> i want to know that what to do if any element is null

You skip it mostly.

> What if I have many fields where types are not known while filtering, can we loop list inside filter and check for n elements each is null or not?

You will have the information regarding types of fields ahead of time, since java is typed language.

The concept of filtering is to include or exclude some portion of data(obviously from alot more) and since all are objects in java you can check for null without a problem(except premitives).

I will use your example with some modifications:

```
Employee[] arrayOfEmps = {
    new Employee(1, "Jeff Bezos", 100000.0), 
    new Employee(5, "Vijay", 700000.0),
    new Employee(2, "Bill Gates", 200000.0), 
    new Employee(4, "Shweta Oza", 500000.0),
    new Employee(0, null, 400000.0),
    null, // note here
    new Employee(3, "Mark Zuckerberg", 300000.0)
};
```

So basically what you have to do for filtering null would be:
`x.filter(Objects::nonNull).x....` or `x.filter(val -> val != null).x...`

More or less the your example will look like:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.stream.*;
public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Employee[] arrayOfEmps = {
                new Employee(1, "Jeff Bezos", 100000.0), 
                new Employee(5, "Vijay", 700000.0),
                new Employee(2, "Bill Gates", 200000.0), 
                new Employee(4, "Shweta Oza", 500000.0),
                new Employee(0, null, 400000.0),
                null, // note here
                new Employee(3, "Mark Zuckerberg", 300000.0)
            };
        List<Employee> result = Arrays.asList(arrayOfEmps).stream().filter(Objects::nonNull).collect(Collectors.toList());
        System.out.println(result);
    }
}
class Employee {
    private int id;
    private String name;
    private double salary;
    
    Employee(int id, String name, double salary) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.salary = salary;
    }
    
   @Override
   public String toString() {
       return "[id: " + this.id +" name: " + this.name + "salary: "+ this.salary + "]";
   }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for solution, Here list is working fine but when we access the element then the problem will occur..
This map will throw an error when it encounters null in the field.
Map<Integer, String> map8 = new HashMap<Integer, String>();
  map8 = result.stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(Employee::getEmpID, Employee::getEmpName));
  System.out.println(map8);